# Problem with instalation ROS 2 "E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop"

Tags: ubuntu, ros2

I try to install ROS 2 on ubuntu focal fosa (20.04).

[I went along with this instruction](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html), but
after implementation this command:

```
sudo apt update
```

I got this problem:

```
Hit:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease                                                                              
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable focal InRelease                                       
Get:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease [4,670 B]
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And after that: `sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop`

I got it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The solution with updating the key does not work for me. This was recommended but did not work: `sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg` Are there any other ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: If  you want that community help you, you should provide us with your error terminal output, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Basically, I had add the new repository key and delete the old one. This was worked for me:

https://answers.ros.org/question/379190/apt-update-signatures-were-invalid-f42ed6fbab17c654/

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the ros-latest.list:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

output: `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main`

Also, dont forget to run `sudo apt update`

This worked for me.